# Issue converting string to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am really tired with converting string to decimal in SQL Server.

This is my query I am trying to convert to decimal

```
DECLARE @price VARCHAR(50)
SET @price = '168,00'

SELECT
    REPLACE(CAST(@price AS DECIMAL(29,2)), '.', ',')

UPDATE MyTable 
SET Invoice = REPLACE(CAST(@price AS DECIMAL(29,2)), '.', ',') 
WHERE ID = 111
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 7
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric

How can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: Do the replace before the cast, not after (you've got them reversed). You're doing cast/replace; you need replace/cast instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace first before doing conversion and must replace comma with period.

```
SET Invoice = CAST(REPLACE(@price, ',', '.') AS decimal(29,2))
```